# Catch all types of error and render 404 page in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

My code is here

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  #before_filter :session_must_exist
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user, :back_url, :parent_url
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception, :with => :method_missing
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :method_missing
    rescue_from AbstractController::ActionNotFound, :with => :method_missing
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :method_missing
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :method_missing
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :method_missing
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    Rails.logger.error(m)
    redirect_to :controller=>"errors", :action=>"error_404"
    render/redirect_to somewhere else
  end
end
```

but it is not working for me. it gives us

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for BuildInstallersController):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:131:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.r
```

Comment: What is the value of `Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that rescue_from is only rescuing from the exceptions occurring within controller and the `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` is a routing issue, so it is raised before controller is instantiated.

You should be able to do what you need with:

```
match '*a', :to => 'errors#error_404'
```

added as the last line to your routes.

However the most elegant solution is to make use of exception_apps like so:

```
# your environment file
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ErrorsController.action(:error_404).call(env) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all in routes.rb file,

```
  if Rails.env.production? # if you want to use it for production environment only
    %w{ 404 422 500 }.each do |err|
      get err, to: "errors#error_#{err}"
    end
  end
```